# Prove that $\frac{1}{x-1}$ is continuous at $x=2$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, continuity

Prove that $\frac{1}{x-1}$ is continuous at $x=2$.

We want to show that $\forall\epsilon>0\exists\delta>0(|x-2|<\delta \implies |\frac{1}{x-1}-1|<\epsilon)$.

We have that $|\frac{1}{x-1}-1|=|\frac{1-x+1}{x-1}|=\frac{|x-2|}{|x-1|}$. Now we need to restrict $x$ to get a bound on the coefficient of $|x-2|$ but I'm unsure on how to do this.

We can restrict $x$ by choosing $\delta>0$ such that $-\delta +2<x<\delta +2$. If we choose $\delta<1$ then $1<x<3$ and $|x-1|$ is unbounded on the interval.

Comment: A simpler way is to recall the following theorem. If $f$ and $g$ are real-valued continuous functions at $x=a$ and $g(a) \ne 0,$ then the quotient $f/g$ is continuous at $x=a.$ Now, consider $f(x)=1$ and $g(x)=x-1$ and $a=2,$ which is your setting. Show that the hypotheses of the aforementioned theorem are met. Can you see why this route would be much easier ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $|x-2|<\frac12$, then $\frac32<x<\frac52$, and therefore $x-1>\frac12$. So$$\left|\frac1{x-1}-1\right|=\frac{|x-2|}{|x-1|}<2|x-2|.$$It follows that, if you take $\delta=\min\left\{\frac12,\frac\varepsilon2\right\}$, then$$|x-2|<\delta\implies\left|\frac1{x-1}-1\right|<\varepsilon.$$

Answer (score 1):

$\frac {|x-2|} {|x-1|}\leq \frac {|x-2|} {1-|x-2|}<\epsilon$ if $|x-2| <\frac {\epsilon} {1+\epsilon}$ (since $|x-1|=|(x-2)+1|\geq 1-|x-2|$). [Note that $|x-2| <\frac {\epsilon} {1+\epsilon}<1$, so $1-|x-2|>0$].

Comment: $|x-1| \geq 1-|x-2| \implies \frac{1}{|x-1|} \leq \frac{1}{1-|x-2|} $ this is true if $1-|x-2|>0$

Comment: @Student See the note I have added.

Comment: It's clear now, thanks.